# What's wrong with the way I'm using PV?

Tags: debian, pipe, memory, pv

I'm using PV to insert a buffer of size 50M between my video recording command and my video streaming command:

```
/usr/bin/raspivid -b 8000000 -w 1280 -h 720 -rot 270 -v -fps 40 -o - -t 0 | pv -B 50M | 
/home/pi/special/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -loglevel debug \
    -framerate 40 \
    -c:v h264 \
    -i - \
    -c:a mp3 \
    -i /tmp/temp_audio.mp3 \
    -c:a copy \
    -c:v copy \
    -f flv rtmp://209.85.230.23/live2/HIDDEN
```

FFMPEg complains:

`'rtmp://209.85.230.23/live2/HIDDEN: Input/output error'`

This only happens when I add PV to my pipeline. I'm clearly using it wrong, but how?